# Creating an Image from a Blob

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, blob

I'd like to store some photos in MySql as blobs and would like to be able to retrieve the binary and recreate images from it to display back to the user.

Everything I've search uses some combination of `file_get_contents`, Base 64 encoding and the GD library. But every post I come across has a different requirement than what I'm trying to do and so the code examples aren't that helpful.

Can someone tell me what function calls I need to make or give me an order of operations for what needs to be done. Say I have the following code:

```
$someBlob = getImageBlobByImageId(1203);
```

Say this blob represents an image named "foo.jpg". How do I go from `$someBlob` to `foo.jpg` so I could put it in HTML like

```
<img src="<?php echo $fooImage; ?>"/>
```

Any hints or nudges in the right direction are greatly appreciated ;-)

Comment: `I'd like to store some photos in MySql as blobs` - it's always bad idea. always.

Comment: I think that's generally not considered a good idea. It's better to store the images separately as real files and just track their names in the database. Some sort of unique, fixed-width filename like timestamp+hash might be a sensible approach.

Comment: Hi @OZ_ - can you educate me as to why? Is there a better way to store images?

Comment: @Courtney as Kerrek said, store the image as a file, and just record the path to the file in your database.

Comment: Hi @Kerrek SB - so do "best practices" dictate that images *never* get stored in persistence? Is there a performance reason here?

Comment: *Nobody* knows why I should just store images on file instead of in the datastore? "Just because" is not a very compelling reason!

Comment: @Courtney: It's just very impractical. You incur lots of back and forth, and there isn't anything useful the database can do for you with the binary data. Since you want to treat the pictures as files, the file system is the natural service for you to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Your HTML needs to point to a PHP script that retrieves the blob and sends it back on request as an image.

For example, in your HTML:

```
<img src="getImage.php?id=1203" />
```

And then, for getImage.php:

```
<?php
    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];
    header("Content-type: image/jpg");
    echo getImageBlobByImageId($id);
    exit();
?>
```

Be sure not to have the script output any content other than the header line and the blob data, or you won't get what you want.